# Is there a way to print out the current line number in a parsed file?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm using the file I/O macros for SV, and I want to print out the number of a parsed line in a file I'm loading and scanning. I couldn't figure out a way to do so. Any help ?

```
statusF  = $fgets(line, input_file);
// Here I would like to print the current line number
statusF  = $sscanf(line, "%h\n", a);
```

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file you are reading has a fixed line size, like in a hex dumpfile, you can use `$ftell` to get the character position and divide (or modulo %) by the line size.

Otherwise you will have count the number of times you called `$fgets`.